# Change engine for "latex" command on terminal

Tags: pdftex, luatex

First of all I'm working with [ePiX](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/current/ePiX.html)

For those who have never heard about, epix uses Latex.

To compile, ePiX runs `latex` command on terminal. I'm always getting a message saying I've got memory limit.

The default engine when I run `latex` on terminal is pdfTeX. I want to change it to LuaLaTeX, it might solve my memory problem.

Any idea about how do that?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I think this is the wrong question to be asking. In the ePiX distribution there is a shell script `laps.in` which sets the options that can be passed to the command. The easiest solution would be to modify a version of that script to accept `lualatex` as an option.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to add an `alias latex=lualatex` to your `.profile`.